# How can I play .bin file with VLC?

Tags: 11.04, video, vlc, video-player

For two days I have tried to get vlc play this `.bin` file. I played it fine in windows xp using vlc. So I decided to install same vlc thats on my xp partition and it plays through Wine the file no problem. Why won't it play natively?

```
fr33bird@fr33bird-desktop:~/Downloads/********/*********$ vlc ********.bin
VLC media player 1.1.10 The Luggage (revision exported)
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_ADDRESS")
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_BUS_TYPE")
[0x8387914] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Blocked: call to setlocale(6, "")
Warning: call to srand(1309627174)
Warning: call to rand()
Blocked: call to setlocale(6, "")

(process:14474): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Blocked: call to setlocale(6, "")
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.1.3
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.10 for DVD access
libdvdread: Can't stat /home/fr33bird/Downloads/*******/*******/*******.bin
No such file or directory
libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
[0x87034e4] filesystem access error: cannot open file /home/fr33bird/Downloads/*****/*****/*******.bin (No such file or directory)
[0x843535c] main input error: open of `file:///home/fr33bird/Downloads/******/****/********.bin' failed: (null)
```

Funny it says no such file even thou it's attempting to read it. Xine says that the `.bin` is encrypted so I installed `libdvdcss2  w32codecs ubuntu-restricted-codecs` from Medibuntu still same issue. How can I fix this? I want to run this natively not through wine. I Even tried to change `.bin` to `.mpg` and `.avi`.

Updated 6-26-2011 Even thou this issue didn't have anything to do with Alsa Audio Output this allows me to play .bin files

*[Alsa doesn't work in vlc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50697/alsa-doesnt-wont-in-vlc)*

Comment: Ubuntu does not care about file extensions. So renaming a file really doesn't make anything better ;). Check what mime type your file has using `file <file>`.

Comment: You should not use special characters like asterisks in file/path names ;-) SCNR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated 6-26-2011 Even thou this issue didn't have anything to do with Alsa Audio Output this allows me to play .bin files

*[Alsa doesn't work in vlc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50697/alsa-doesnt-work-in-vlc)*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing Xine and installing Gstreamer codecs for ubuntu?  Personally, I prefer gstreamer over xine as it has always had better/smoother playback in ubuntu.

Comment: I already have gstreamer installed all 4 or 5 of them in ubuntu software center. Althou i did Remove xine still no go same issue

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution and I can't personally test this as I don't have any BIN files to try this out on, but you can try this workaround found on the ubuntufourms.org archive posts (http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-282288.html): (1) rename .bin to .mpg (2) if you get no sound than switch over the audio track to Track 2 [right click on the video "Audio"-> "Audio Track"]

Comment: No go bro but thanks i had already tried that before i posted but thanks for trying to help bro.

Answer (score 0):

I read "No such file or directory", so the problem is not vlc, but probably something like the interface between the shell and the program: there are spaces in the name of the file, or some other strange characters? If so, begin trying to put the file name between double quotes, or better single quotes:

```
vlc 'long file name.bin'
```

Comment: I thought so to before i posted i had also renamed with no spaces or - . So now its labels like <code> 1986somefile.bin have also tried 1986somefile.mpg </code> and also tried without numbers. tyhanks for trying but i still have same issue. I can play it from gui and get no video and sound is very choppy.