# Alsa doesn't work in vlc

Tags: 11.04, sound, vlc, alsa

Alsa Audio Output works fine from terminal, e.g. `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav`.

But I got to change from default to Alsa Audio Output in vlc. I found it in *Tools > Perfernces > Audio > Outputs*.

The issue is that when I change it to Alsa, I Loose all sound. When I leave the default I get an annoying Audio delay of about 200ms or 500ms. From what I have found you have to use Alsa Audio Outpu to fix that issue.

Comment: put the fix on the the answer section below not on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the original author*

To fix the Alsa Audio Output:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/vlc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

then, open Update Manager, there were 2 updates for vlc there, install them and reboot. Now alsa works fine and audio is in sync with video.

Answer (score 0):

After todays update to the 1.1.12 version of VLC and using Ubuntu 11.10. Most if not all out of sync problems are gone.

Users need to update their Ubuntu to the latest daily updates which should provide the latest version of VLC (the 1.1.12 version). Already tested and all movies I have seen are working correctly.